# Fonte pequena - PhoneGap

Tags: css, apache-cordova

Não consigo fazer com que a fonte fique em tamanho bom no PhoneGap, já tentei usar %, px, em e nada resolve.

O código de onde está a fonte é:

```
.header-page p {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
/*    font-size: 22px;*/
    font-size: 100%;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #d5a053;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

E a imagem de como o texto fica:
[http://imgur.com/IhMDMwH](https://imgur.com/IhMDMwH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não uso o phonegap e não o conheço profundamente. Porém o problema de legibilidade das fontes em celulares e outros dispositivos móveis na maioria das vezes é a falta da meta tag:

`<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />`

Essa tag faz com que o texto se adapte e fique no 'tamanho real' em dispositivos móveis.

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso parece que o problema se dá por causa do viewport, e não da fonte em si.

Adicionando esta metatag deve resolver:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```